# how to keep file ownership while using tar

Tags: perl, unix, tar

I am currently writing an automatic backup script for our servers. i am using the UNIX tar command in the script to archive the code repositories.

in my PERL script i am using the tar command as follows:

```
system("tar -jcpf $destPath/$string.tar.bz2 -X $exclusionFile $targetPath");
```

i want to keep file ownerships when extracting the tar archive. i tried to list the tar archive contents with

```
tar -jtvf
```

and the list contained the correct file ownerships for each file, but when extracting the archive, the file ownership changes to the current user.

is there any way to extract a tar archive and keep the original file ownerships for each file?

Comment: I'll quickly add: Don't do a `system` command when you can do it in pure Perl. Look at [Archive::Tar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html). It's part of the standard Perl package for quite a while. It will work in various operating systems and give you better control over your tarball.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Supply the option `--same-owner` to tar while *extracting*.

`tar --help` tells:

```
   --same-owner
          create extracted files with the same ownership
```

Comment: i tried to extract the tar archive:

 tar --same-owner -jxvf naveExample2.tbz2

 while extracting the tar and got the following errors:

tar: backup/superlinksnpTest.txt: Cannot change ownership to uid 50537, gid 50538: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

am i doing it wrong?

Comment: You must be `root` to enable `tar` to change the UID/GID of the archive's contents.

Comment: Not all implementation of `tar` include the `--same-owner` parameter, or even have the `--help` flag. Always do `man tar` to see what optional parameters your version of `tar` has.

Comment: Thank you. I had the opposite problem while running install scripts as root, resulting in archives being extracted with whatever odd owner/group combination the archive was created with. In my case the desired option was --no-same-owner to achieve the opposite effect - change the default behaviour of tar extract for the superuser.

Answer (score 5):

You want to "preserve" file attributes while doing `tar -x` with the `-p` switch. Obviously you need to be root for this to to have the desired result.

```
         -p, --insecure, --preserve-permissions
         (x mode only) Preserve file permissions.  Attempt to restore the
         full permissions, including owner, file modes, file flags and
         ACLs, if available,
```

Many POSIX systems also ship `pax`, `cpio` that can work as alternatives to `tar`.